# Android - WebView - scrolling to selected id

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, scroll

The HTML file I have created a map of the world. Idea: after clicking on a map of a country (it has its id), the map has to scroll to the place where the country place and centred.

In HTML I gave the function code:

```
function scrollToElement(id) {

    var elem = document.getElementById(id);

    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    while (elem != null) {
        x += elem.offsetLeft;
        y += elem.offsetTop;
        elem = elem.offsetParent;
    }
    window.scrollTo(x, y);
}
```

And in the right place in Java file I added the code for calling this function with the passed parameter:

```
web_wiev.loadUrl("javascript:scrollToElement('" + msgeToast + "')");
```

Where: msgeToast is forwarded id.
Unfortunately, the map does not scroll (sometimes it scrolls, but not where it's needed, sometimes it does not scroll at all).
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: did you tested your javascript method??

Comment: Yes, I tested. The method is performed. When I added an entry to it: elem.style.visibility = "hidden"; the element disappeared. So there is a scrolling problem.

Comment: your `loadUrl()` call is just for test right? Since what you want is clicking on a map from WebView then call `scrollToElement(id)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function scrollTo(element){
            document.getElementById(element).scrollIntoView();
        }
```